# NeoVim ugly text next to variable assignment

Tags: python, neovim, neovim-plugin

Using NeoVim, I created a Python file for a new project, and noticed that now when I declare a new variable, and go back to normal mode, a text appears looking like this:

```
a = 1 : Literal[1]
b = 'hello' : Literal['hello']
c = ['a', 'random', 'list'] : list[str]
```

I am not sure it comes from that, but I use coc-nvim for autocompletion.

Where does this text come from?

Comment: Just to clarify, the offending text is the `: Literal[1]` etc at the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, I just want a = 1 in the first line for example.

Comment: Is this text inserted in the file, or displayed as overlay?

Comment: It is an overlay, I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are inferred type hints.

If you want to deactivate them this is what you can do:

1. Go to your coc-settings.json
2. Add `"inlayHint.enable": false`

Check `:h coc-inlayHint` and `:h coc-config-inlayHint` for more